# What is the name of the circle with minor axis of an ellipse as its diameter?

Tags: geometry, terminology, circles, conic-sections

The following image shows an ellipse (orange) and two concentric circles (green) with centre at the centre of the ellipse:

[image]

[Image Source](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1603147/693070)

The outer circle is the one with the major axis as its diameter and is called the [Auxiliary circle](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AuxiliaryCircle.html). The inner circle's diameter is the minor axis of the ellipse. Do we have any special name for the inner circle as we have for the outer one?

I am unable to find any relevant information on the internet.

Comment: I've never heard of a term for this before, but would use "inscribed circle" and "circumscribed circle" for the two circles.  The term "auxiliary circle" strikes me as being uninformative.

Comment: Never heard of a name for the inner circle.

Answer (score 2):

The term "auxiliary circle" does not seem to be in wide usage these days, but you can find it in various texts.  Generally, the circumscribed and inscribed circles are referred to respectively as "the major auxiliary circle" and "the minor auxiliary circle" and generically as "auxiliary circles," according to [Runkle's Plane Analytic Geometry (1888)](https://books.google.ca/books?id=0asLAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA237&lpg=PA237&dq=minor%20auxiliary%20circle&source=bl&ots=0y-VxD1yzE&sig=ACfU3U3iQUsy5c6vlEWRg6d0fnMM2SS-_Q&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwin3vbo3t3lAhXrQd8KHeFnDCIQ6AEwD3oECAsQAQ#v=onepage&q=auxiliary%20circles&f=false)

Some other views of the same book and topic on archive.org are [here](https://archive.org/details/elementsplanean00runkgoog/page/n250) and [here](https://archive.org/details/elementsplanean00runkgoog/page/n200).

You can also take a look at [Abbott's Practical Geometry](https://books.google.ca/books?id=1LDsCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA28&lpg=PA28&dq=minor%20auxiliary%20circle&source=bl&ots=2fzK6w6CZv&sig=ACfU3U2iN1uPNXHqlG20Olv_4QMjM2kW6w&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjRntrR5d3lAhXGg-AKHUEmANwQ6AEwDnoECAYQAQ#v=onepage&q=minor%20auxiliary%20circle&f=false), and search for "Practical Geometry" on archive.org to find books that use the term.