# Reasoning behind the $y$ coordinate of a point on an ellipse in the parametric form

Tags: geometry, circles, conic-sections

The following image is from [*this answer*](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1603344/693070) for the question [*How to prove the parametric equation of an ellipse?*](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1603147/693070), and shows an ellipse (red) and two concentric circles (black) with diameters equal to the major and minor axes of the ellipse, with centre at the centre of the ellipse:

[image]

The coordinates of the point $P$ in the parametric form is $(a\cos\theta,b\sin\theta)$ where $\theta$ is the angle $AOH$ and $a,b$ are the lengths of the semi-major and semi-minor axes respectively.

I can understand, since $AH$ is perpendicular to $DE$, the $x$ coordinate of $A$ is same as that of $P$ which is $a\cos\theta$.

But, I am unable to understand why the $y$ coordinate of the point $P$ is $b\sin\theta$. According to the previously mentioned [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1603147/693070)/[answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1603344/693070), I think we are supposed to understand like this - since $BP$ is parallel to $DE$ the $y$ coordinates of $B$ and $P$ are the same, which is $b\sin\theta$. But, I am unable to understand this fact due to the following:

- Why must $BP$ be parallel to $DE$?
- A line perpendicular to $AH$ passing through $P$ (or a line parallel to $DE$ passing through $P$) will pass for sure through the inner circle. But why should this point lie on the line $AO$?

To be concise, kindly explain why is the $y$ coordinate of a point in a ellipse in the parametric form $b\sin\theta$?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Point $P$ is *constructed* that way: by projecting $A$ to $H$ on diameter $DE$ and then projecting $B$ to $P$ on $AH$. The ellipse is the locus of $P$ while $A$ makes a complete turn of the outer circle.

Comment: @Aretino, Thank you. Why should the projection of $B$ on $AH$ necessarily be at $P$? I think, it may also intersect at some other point on $AH$.

Comment: How do you think $P$ is defined? I wrote my definition above.

Comment: In other words: $P$ is not defined as the intersection of $BP$ with the ellipse, it is the other way around: the ellipse is defined as the locus of $P$.

Comment: @Aretino, I understand. But suppose we fix the ellipse, and the two circles. Now let us drop a perpendicular from point $A$ which meets the ellipse at $P$. $B$ is some point on the inner circle which also lies on $OA$. How to say $BP$ is parallel to $DE$? I don't think there must be any huge difference if we define alternatively, as the end result must be same.

Comment: You should then prove that, for instance by reversing the reasoning I used in that answer. The proof will depend on the definition of ellipse you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question you mentioned defined the ellipse as the locus of point $P$ and asked to prove that this was in agreement with the two-foci definition of ellipse. That seems to have little to do with your actual question.

If you define $P$ as the point with coordinates $(a\cos\theta,b\sin\theta)$ then it is obvious that $PB$ is parallel to the $x$-axis, because the coordinates of $B$ are $(b\cos\theta,b\sin\theta)$: points $P$ and $B$ have the same $y$-coordinate.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Even if we don't define $P$ as $(a\cos\theta,b\sin\theta)$, we may obtain the $y$ coordinate from the fact that $x$ coordinate is $a\cos\theta$ and use this in the general equation of the ellipse.